# jsonify flask parsing error

Tags: jquery, json, flask

To make it simple, ajax receives a jsonify response from flask and I can't find the way to render it in the html.
I tried :

```
success: function(json) {
    $.each(json, function(index, element) {
        $('#main').append(element.title);
    });
}
```

and got "undefined" printed.

Then I tried :

```
 $('#main').append(json[index].name)
```

but nothing got printed

Here's the json returned by the api :

```
{
  "albums": [
    {
      "artist_id": 19,
      "composer_id": 3,
      "id": 6,
      "img": "The_Fine_Art_of_Self_Destruction.jpg",
      "release_date": 2002,
      "title": "the fine art of self destruction"
    },
    {
      "artist_id": 26,
      "composer_id": 6,
      "id": 22,
      "img": "The_Blasters_%28album%29.jpg",
      "release_date": 1981,
      "title": "the blasters"
    },
    {
      "artist_id": 25,
      "composer_id": 6,
      "id": 25,
      "img": "XMoreFunInTheNewWorld.jpg",
      "release_date": 1983,
      "title": "more fun in the new world"
    },
    {
      "artist_id": 27,
      "composer_id": 8,
      "id": 28,
      "img": "220px-The_Angels_of_Light_Sing_%27Other_People%27.jpeg",
      "release_date": 2005,
      "title": "the angels of light sing 'other people'"
    },
    {
      "artist_id": 10,
      "composer_id": 10,
      "id": 32,
      "img": null,
      "release_date": 2008,
      "title": "when the flood comes"
    },
    {
      "artist_id": 31,
      "composer_id": 15,
      "id": 40,
      "img": "The_Willies.jpg",
      "release_date": 2002,
      "title": "the willies"
    }
  ]
}
```

I looked over many things like jQuery.parseJSON() and others but nothing worked.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: `json[index].name` supposed to be `json.albums[index].name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $.each(json, function(index, element) {
```

should be

```
 $.each(json.albums, function(index, element) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your code to

```
$.each(json.albums, function(index, element) {
        $('#main').append(element.title);
    });
```